# How does 2FA Recovery Codes work in .NET 3.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

Currently in a brand new .NET 3.0 app when a user registers and enables 2FA the user can not login using the recovery codes that are generated. The question I'd like to ask is how does a user log in to my app if they have lost their authenticator app? I have tried to do this using boilerplate code generated by executing the following code.

```
dotnet new webapp --auth Individual
```

I've found the article that describes to scaffold the Identity pages but still can't figure it out. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe if someone can point me in the right direction to where the code for "UserManager.RedeemTwoFactorRecoveryCodeAsync" is located on GitHub then I can review it and figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue. Instead of entering all of the codes that were generated I needed only enter in one of the codes that were generated. I hope this helps anyone else who is confused on how this works.